# Is HTTPS required for any Sonos service in a developer sandbox?

Tags: ssl, sonos

I have the Sonos Acme developer test service setup and running but my Sonos Player doesn't seem to be able to connect. I'm wondering if a TLS SSL certificate is required no matter what even in a sandboxed environment.

I'm running the java service on a remote AWS instance behind a domain. The service is setup with the default installation details. It does not log any sort of connection attempt once I add the service to the Sonos player via customSD.

Accessing the Sonos Player via customSD and adding the Acme service does respond with Success! But again it doesn't show up in the service list. Manually pulling the WSDL does work correctly via the http request.

Also to note that Sonos seems to be in the middle of creating it's new developer portal and since last Monday ( June 24th ) the new portal no longer references the Acme test service. I'm wondering if this is due to it no longer being valid and it's documentation out of date (est. 2017-2018).

I expect the service to show up in the Sonos Controller when adding a new service but it doesn't appear and the log doesn't show any attempts to connect.

Comment: The service showing in the app has nothing to do with the functionality of your service. Once you have done customSD it should show up in the app. But if it is not showing in the app, how are you even getting a player to try and connect?

Comment: I run the service remotely on AWS and I do get a success message from customSD but nothing lists in the controller list. That's sort of my issue and I'm wondering if it's due to not having any https even though there's no auth and also if it's became dev would have to be done via the local network the speaker is one vs an remote AWS instance. Going to test both next week.

Answer (score 0):

An SSL endpoint is required for production, but you can use a non-SSL endpoint for testing. See the comments in this answer for details: [With a Sonos player, adding local service to customSD does not show up Music Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57281874/with-a-sonos-player-adding-local-service-to-customsd-does-not-show-up-music-ser/57383330)