# With a Sonos player, adding local service to customSD does not show up Music Services

Tags: sonos

I have the starting shell of a SMAPI service programmed in Node.js. The service is running off of a local IP address.

When I goto the customSD page for my Sonos Play:1 and add the service details to it and it returns 'Success!' upon clicking submit.

When I open the Sonos Controllers on both my desktop and mobile, the service does not show up in the list of music services you can add.

I have logging on the server turned on to max and there are no connection attempts ( either SSL or HTTP ) at all.

From what I've read, a running service is not needed for it to show up in the list. Once it's added via customSD it should show up in the Music Service settings.

TO NOTE: A self signed cert is being used for https for connection testing only. I have certificate request logging turned on and there is NO connection attempt from the Sonos Play:1 to the local server at all. From everything I've read this shouldn't matter as it should show up in the Music Service list until you try to add it and then it will connect to the service.

The only thing I can think of is if this service needs to be registered with Sonos before it can be added via customSD, however at this time nothing I've read says that.

The other thing is if this service needs to be running off a domain name for some reason. However in the documentation it lists IP address so it would be bad documentation then.

I expect the service added via customSD should show up in the list. It does not appear when clicking on add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understood the issue and YvesGrantSonos has updated the documentation.

If you're developing locally a non-https IP address should be used for both the secure and non-secure API URI's.

Comment: Updated the Secure Endpoint URL doc to describe that you can enter an IP address as the non-SSL endpoint. See [Test your service](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-get-started/test-your-content-service/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able enter a local IP address for the SMAPI service. For testing, this should be on the same local network as the Sonos player. Be sure to include the port number that the service is running on (i.e. http://192.168.1.2:8080/musicservice). You can use the same IP and port for secure and insecure connections.

Comment: this was done multiple ways with the sonos connecting to my laptop on the same network. It was also done using a remote server's IP. Nothing worked until a Domain name was used at which point the sonos added the service.

Comment: Was the Sonos player connected to a router or to your laptop? It should be connected to the same router as the one that your sample server is on. Can you reproduce the issue with the [SMAPI sample server](https://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/509)?

Comment: With the SMAPI sample server. I tested several cases.

The laptop was running a wifi network bridging the LAN. The Sonos was using the laptops wifi network and unable to connect. No firewall was active.
In a different setup both devices were using the same WIFI router.
In a different case the remote IP based server on AWS running on port 8080.

What finally worked was building a new server with it's own domain name. The sonos finally connected to it.

Comment: Hi Peter. I'm still following up, but it looks like you're right. If using HTTPS, your SMAPI service must have a valid host name that DNS can resolve that matches your certificate. If you're using HTTP, you can use a static IP address. You should be able to use HTTP for testing both endpoints.

Comment: Hi Yves, I discovered the same thing, in rebuilding the java project all over again I realized you can use the HTTP url for the secure link in testing. 

One note I would recommend making that more apparent in the docs because it's only in the java readme that it says 'enter the IP in both URLS' but everyone else in your website it says 'You must use a a TLS link' which is where I became confused.

I was able to get the java project running localhost great now!

Comment: That's great to hear, Peter! Thanks for finding this. I updated the Secure Endpoint URL doc on the [Test your service](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-get-started/test-your-content-service/) page to describe that you can enter the non-SSL endpoint for testing.